# Parser error expected " but got indentifer

Tags: solidity, parser

```
    constructor(
    address _DEMO,
    address _principle,
    address _treasury,
    address _DAO,
    address _bondCalculator
) {
    require(_DEMO != address(0));
    DEMO = _DEMO;
    require(_principle != address(0));
    principle = _principle;
    require(_treasury != address(0));
    treasury = _treasury;
    require(_DAO != address(0));
    DAO = "_DAO;"
    // bondCalculator should be address(0) if not LP bond
    bondCalculator = _bondCalculator;
     isLiquidityBond = (_bondCalculator != address(0));
}
```

This is my code here but when i try to compile it in remix i keep getting that parser error from the title on the bondCalculator =_bondcalculator; line.I don't know what is wrong with my code as it looks alright to me but I am a inexperienced coder and feedback is greatly appreciated

Comment: Hi, I would like to help, but could you edit your question so the code is more readable. Thanks.

Comment: Hi sorry i just edited it there it should be more readable

Answer (score 1):

I created new contract named Test.sol and added your code "edited". It now compiles. Though there are many warnings about unused variables. But that is okay for learning code.

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.7.0;

contract Test {


 constructor (
    address _DEMO,
    address _principle,
    address _treasury,
    address _DAO,
    address _bondCalculator
) public {
    require(_DEMO != address(0));
    address DEMO = _DEMO;
    require(_principle != address(0));
    address principle = _principle;
    require(_treasury != address(0));
    address treasury = _treasury;
    require(_DAO != address(0));
    address DAO = _DAO;
    // bondCalculator should be address(0) if not LP bond
    address bondCalculator = _bondCalculator;
    bool isLiquidityBond = (_bondCalculator != address(0));
}
```